# how to sort data by created_date and updated_date together

Tags: mysql

I have data that have created_date,updated_date and updated_date can be null.
I am trying to sort data by created_date and updated_date together
if data got updated_date it will use updated_date
if data does not have updated_date but created_date > other data updated_date it will come first

[image]

this is a result that I used
"ORDER BY `books`.`display_updated` DESC , `books`.`display_created` DESC"

data that updated_date is null came under.
Could you please suggest me ?

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription effort? **Please don't use images of data**, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to create ascii tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [coalesce()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
ORDER BY COALESECE(updated_date, created_date)
```

I prefer that function over `ifnull()` because coalesce is ANSI standard, but you could use

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(updated_date, created_date)
```

Either of the approaches test if `updated_date` is null and if it is will return `created_date` otherwise it returns 'updated_date'. Both the above equate to this `case expression`, which is another alternative:

```
order by case when updated_date IS NOT NULL then updated_date else created_date end
```